# Can't do texlive package updating

Tags: lyx, texlive, tlmgr

tlmgr command doesn't work.

As was instructed by this page on texlive (https://tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html), I typed commands to update texlive packages but none of them do any job. I type it, and nothing happens. No sign that the computer did any job after my commands like "tlmgr update --all"

Why is that?

[image]

And this is my texlive folder. Anything strange?

[image]

If I type it at the tlmgr directory, it still says strange things like this:

[image]

Comment: Same comment as your other question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627335/cannot-do-disaster-recovery-for-texlive#comment1564564_627335'll

Comment: Try to start `cmd.exe` in [administrator mode](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=57).

Comment: One possibility is that initially you install it as administrator or something, then a normal user can't rewrite it. I guess the easiest fix would be to delete the whole texlive folder and reinstall from scratch. <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627335/cannot-do-disaster-recovery-for-texlive#comment1564564_627335>

Comment: Additionally, you have texlive 2019, which cannot be updated anymore. Generally "TeXLive Year" is only updated for about a year.