# Cannot do disaster recovery for texlive

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

Following the advice here (https://tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html) which says

> the simplest way forward is to download and run update-tlmgr-latest.sh
> (Unix) or  update-tlmgr-latest.exe (Windows). These are
> self-extracting archives which include  all the infrastructure files.
> Running them should restore tlmgr to a coherent state

I downloaded it and ran it, but it simply shows me this:

What's wrong?

[image]

Also, it bans me from installing update-tlmgr-latest.exe in the bin directory.

[image]

Comment: One possibility is that initially you install it as administrator or something, then a normal user can't rewrite it. I guess the easiest fix would be to delete the whole texlive folder and reinstall from scratch.

Comment: @user202729 I deleted the whole texlive and reinstalled it. Now it works. Though it took a long time..

Comment: @user1849133 so? answer the question yourself?